# Qt error: invalid expression of abstract class

Tags: c++, qt, class, abstract

I m having some troubles with the following error(s).

> **mijnanimatie.cpp:3: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'QGraphicsItem'**
>
> **mijnAnimatie::mijnAnimatie(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), graphicsPointer (new QGraphicsItem(this)), painter (new QPainter(this)), angle(0)**

I did already look up this error on the forum, but it didn't help.

**My goal:**

Trying to call a the function `mijnAnimatie::rotate()` of another class when my `pushbutton` is clicked, nothing more.

Comment: It's an abstract base class.  From the [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qgraphicsitem.html): `To write your own graphics item, you first create a subclass of QGraphicsItem, and then start by implementing its two pure virtual public functions: boundingRect(), which returns an estimate of the area painted by the item, and paint(), which implements the actual painting.`

Comment: The documentation I linked contains an example.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't waste time on the QtWidgets stack, just go for QML. It is beginner friendly, fast and easy to work with, and simpler than C++.